# Apache Zeppelin 0.8 SNAPSHOT build from source failed

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am trying to build Apache Zeppelin 0.8 SNAPSHOT using the source on GitHub.
Zeppelin Server build is failing with errors, any idea on the root cause for build failure?

> [INFO] Zeppelin: Server ................................... FAILURE [
> 16.743 s]
>
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Jupyter Support .......................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Packaging distribution ................... SKIPPED
>
> [INFO]
>
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> [INFO]
>
> [INFO] Total time: 26.483 s
>
> [INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-23T05:20:34-07:00
>
> [INFO] Final Memory: 68M/341M
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
> (default-compile) on project zeppelin-server: Compilation failure:
> Compilation failure: [ERROR]
> /home/apache/zeppelin/zeppelin-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/server/CorsFilter.java:[86,76]
> cannot find symbol
>
> [ERROR] symbol:   method getStrictTransport()
>
> [ERROR] location: variable zeppelinConfiguration of type
> org.apache.zeppelin.conf.ZeppelinConfiguration
>
> [ERROR]
> /home/apache/zeppelin/zeppelin-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/server/CorsFilter.java:[88,65]
> cannot find symbol
>
> [ERROR] symbol:   method getXxssProtection() [ERROR] location:
> variable zeppelinConfiguration of type
> org.apache.zeppelin.conf.ZeppelinConfiguration
>
> [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
> the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
> please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with
> the command
>
> [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :zeppelin-server

Comment: I am trying to build it on Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you provide the build command? As far as i know,  zeppelin-server is dependent on zeppelin-interpreter,zeppelin-zengine and so on. I guess you missed it.

Comment: Let's try `mvn clean package -DskipTests;`

Comment: RESOLVED: Looks like the issue is with Scala version 2.11. I have configured zeppelin build to use Scala 2.10 and found no issues in the build.

Comment: If you want to build with scala-2.11, run `./dev/change_scala_version.sh 2.11` first.

Comment: I tried scala 2.11, no luck. Actually, with scala 2.11 not just server other modules have build issues.